# Converting a Python dict to Octave equivalent

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, octave

What is the definition of `dict` in Python?

What is the equivalent in Octave or MATLAB, if there is a difference between them?

Python:

```
return dict(Fx = fxp, Fy = fyp, MO = MOp)
```

I would be grateful of any suggestions.

Comment: You could "emulate" the associative nature of Pythons dictionaries with Matlabs structs, since Pythons `d["key"] = value` is not too different from Matlabs `s.('key') = value;` But certainly, it is not the same and not as efficient.

Comment: In MATLAB you can use [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html), but this is not implemented in Octave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `dict` is an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  There is no direct equivalent in Octave.

Update: Florian suggests that matlab structs can provide similar functionality.

> You could "emulate" the associative nature of Pythons dictionaries with Matlabs structs, since Pythons d["key"] = value is not too different from Matlabs s.('key') = value; But certainly, it is not the same and not as efficient

Comment: ok thank you but do you have a Suggestion , how can i code it in MATLAB or Octave

Comment: In your cited example it is little more than a three element array.  It is just that you will need to keep track of the fact that the three elements are Fx, Fy and Mo.  Or see @florian suggestion on your post.

Comment: i don´t understand ...what he want to say when he wrote the code so ...why he didn´t wrote it as : Fx = fxp Fy = fyp MO = MOp

Comment: "What he want to say"? If you have been given this code by someone else and don't know the code's function, you will never translate it to another language very successfully. If it works to just define an array then why not do that? You don't have to directly emulate every line, just the functionality...

Comment: The python dict allows the three pieces of data to be returned as a single entity, and then later each of the three pieces can be accessed using their names (Fx, Fy, Mo).  VERY convenient.  But it is just three pieces of information, you can store them however you like.